# Performing simple network call to retrieve JSON in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have looked at the network documentation for Unity and most examples seem to be related to networking your game for multiplayer. I am just looking to grab a JSON response from an api for dynamically generating a menu. Is there some good examples for doing just simple network calls to get a response from a web server?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get this from a web API? If so, you may want to look into the WWW class instead.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for but I can't mark it as accepted because it is a comment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I expanded it to an answer, with a little more detail and some links in case anyone else is directed here for info.

Comment: Closed, as you cross posted to gamedev (where you got your answer)

Comment: Nothing about this question is "too localized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For access to a web based API it would be easiest to use the WWW class in Unity.

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html

Make sure to check the documentation about using it asynchronously, or it can block execution while waiting for the web server to respond (or not respond).

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C# and not targeting Webplayer or iOS, you can use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and a library like [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) if you like (if you have past experience with these classes instance). You will likely need to spend a little extra time properly handling the request asychronously.

There is also Unity's [`WWW` class](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) where you would inspect and parse the resulting `text` property. The `WWW` class has the advantage of requiring very little code to perform the request asynchronously.

Note that without making such a request asynchronously you can easily block progress in the rest of the game loop, which is almost always not desirable.

Answer (score -8):

I'd call `wget $urlOfApi --header=Accept:application/json -O file.json` and read in file.json.

Comment: This is not unity related or even C#.

Comment: @tyoc213 Sure, but it is how I would solve the problem. If you can't use more than one tool... that sucks.

Comment: Definitely not the way to solve this problem.